# JSON Naming issue using Lastfm API

Tags: c#, json, api

Im fairly new to API's and JSON so please bear with me...

I want to consume information about Albums from last fm's API, i can consume everything bar the images as there seems to be a naming issue.

The section of the api:

```
   "image": [{
        "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/88057565.png",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/88057565.png",
        "size": "medium"
    },
    {
        "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/174s\/88057565.png",
        "size": "large"
    },
    {
        "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/88057565.png",
        "size": "extralarge"
    },
    {
        "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/_\/88057565\/Believe.png",
        "size": "mega"
    }],
```

After running the JSON through JSON2CSharp I get:

```
public class Image
{
public string __invalid_name__#text { get; set; }
public string size { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously this is no good, So could anyone point me in the right direction of a way to solve my issue?
Is it possible to rename them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Json.NET for parsing their API responses, and used the JsonProperty attribute to map #text to a valid property name, as follows:

```
public class ArtistImage
{
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("#text")]
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

My code's on CodePlex if you want it: https://concertfinder.codeplex.com/
But basically once you have your classes defined you just use a JsonSerializer to Deserialize(jsonData).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, it says my 'JsonProperty' could not be found? any ideas?

Comment: JSon.net... sorry missed the reference

Comment: Yeah, just make sure you include that nuget package - if you have any other troubles getting it to work let me know.  I used Json.NET because I think it makes the ser/deser process a lot easier to fine-tune.