# Json Naming issue

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, json.net

I am New to JSON and API
I am trying to get some data from an API for which I have Json and want to make a class for it.when I convert it using josn2csharp I get following code. Please let me know what sholud be the proper format of my class so that it converts into json.

```
public class DataSet {
    public string __invalid_name__-i:nil { get; set; } }

public class GenericObject {
    public string __invalid_name__-xmlns:d2p1 { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__-i:type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__#text { get; set; } }

public class Message {
    public string __invalid_name__-i:nil { get; set; } }

public class FunctionResponse {
    public string __invalid_name__-xmlns:i { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__-xmlns { get; set; }
    public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }
    public GenericObject GenericObject { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public string Success { get; set; } }

public class RootObject {
    public FunctionResponse FunctionResponse { get; set; } }
```

use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999985/json-naming-issue-using-lastfm-api) question as reference in this I came to know how to write for

public string **invalid_name**#text { get; set; }

but what about others.
please help

edit 1:

```
{
   "DataSet": {
      "@nil": "true"
   },
   "GenericObject": {
      "@type": "d2p1:boolean",
      "#text": "true"
   },
   "Message": {
      "@nil": "true"
   },
   "Success": "true"
}
```

Comment: As described in the answer of the question referred by you, you can name your properties anything make sure the JsonProperty parameter matched the keys of the json you are going to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
{
 "json": 
   {
   "#thekeyinsidejsonproperty": "value"
   }
}
```

you shoud have

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("json")]
    public Json jsonobj;

}

 public class Json
{
    [JsonProperty("#thekeyinsidejsonproperty")]
    public string somepropertyname{ get; set; }

}
```

hope it helps! :)

Comment: that means for "DataSet": { "-i:nil": "true" }, I can write public class DataSet
    {
        [JsonProperty("-i:nil")]
        public string Idata { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Is this what I have to do

Comment: public class DataSet { [JsonProperty("-i:nil")] public string Idata { get; set; } }

your json should be  { "-i:nil": "true" } not "DataSet": { "-i:nil": "true" }

Comment: Or else have your class as 

public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("DataSet")]
        public DataSet dataSet;

    }

if your very strict about your json -- {"DataSet": { "-i:nil": "true" }}

Comment: go ahead with the class structure i have given it should work (Y).